# How do I include a time condition in this sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app that uses the custom sql string (with a postgres database) shown below. That string works fine. I'm trying to add a time condition into the query so that I only retrieve records from answer_votes, best_answers and contributions that were created within the last 7 days. Therefore, I got today's date and subtracted 7 days

```
date = Date.today - 7
```

and substituted the statements in the sql string below for something like this

```
(select Coalesce(sum(value),0) from answer_votes  where (answer_votes.user_id = users.id) AND (answer_votes.created_at <= #{date}))
```

However, it's giving me several errors

```
PG::Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <= integer
```

Can you show me the correct way to do this. Note, although I only showed my attempt for answer_votes, I'll be trying to do the same for best_answers and contributions, however, the solution will be the same (I assume).

```
sql_string = "with cte_scoring as (
  select
    users.id, users.name, users.email,
    (select Coalesce(sum(value),0) from answer_votes  where answer_votes.user_id = users.id) +
    (select Coalesce(sum(value),0) from best_answers  where best_answers.user_id = users.id) +
    (select Coalesce(sum(value),0) from contributions where contributions.user_id = users.id) total_score
  from
    users join
    contacts on (contacts.user_id = users.id)
  where
    users.lawyer         = 'true')   

select   id,
         name,
         email,
         total_score
from     cte_scoring
order by total_score desc
limit    2 "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in Postgres functions for this purpose:

```
where . . . created_at <= Current_Date - interval '7 day'
```

Something is probably going wrong with the variable substitution.  You probably need single quotes around the date variable.  But, doing this inside the database is simpler.